# Retrieving coordinate positions using ChemicalData for input to quanutm modelling software

Tags: curated-data, chemistry

I am trying to set up an input file for a quantum chemical modelling software. How do I obtain the (XYZ) coordinate positions in Angstroms using information obtained using ChemicalData. Have some initial input for fructose below:

```
ChemicalData["Fructose", "AtomPositions"]
```

What I expect in the output (just an example not the actual positions)

```
                 Coordinates (Angstroms)
 ATOM                X               Y               Z
  1  C        2.5130891440   -0.0345557109   -0.2500995821
  2  O         0.0459435630    3.3652982874    1.6477735205
  3  H        0.0347565292    2.5110247340    0.2498797086
.......
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's first pre-process the data you need for the output file to be used in your quantum simulation software:

```
pos = ChemicalData["Fructose", "AtomPositions"][[1]]/100.;
atype = ChemicalData["Fructose", "VertexTypes"][[1]];  
data = Transpose[{atype, pos}];
```

Here's a function to give you the output file the way you specified in your question:

```
writeXYZ[file_String, data_] := 
   Module[{str = OpenWrite[file, FormatType -> OutputForm], len = Length @ data}, 
     Scan[WriteLine[str, #] &, {ToString @ len, " Coordinates (Angstroms)"}]; 
     Scan[Write[str, " ", data[[#, 1]], PaddedForm[data[[#, 2, 1]], {14, 6}], 
       PaddedForm[data[[#, 2, 2]], {10, 6}], 
       PaddedForm[data[[#, 2, 3]], {10, 6}]] &, Range @ len]; 
     Close[str]
   ]
```

Now, let's use it:

```
writeXYZ["test.xyz", data]
```

We can view the file to see what it looks like:

```
FilePrint["test.xyz"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And here is what it looks like when imported

```
Import["test.xyz", "XYZ"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Plot with Mathematica**

```
radii = QuantityMagnitude @ Map[ElementData[#, "VanDerWaalsRadius"] &, atype] / 100.;
color = Map[ColorData["Atoms", #] &, atype];
```

Then:

```
Graphics3D[{Specularity[White, 40], MapThread[{#1, Sphere[#2, #3 / 1.2]} &, {color, pos, radii}]}, 
     Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The VMD viewer is OK, but is it possible to use the higher resolution Graphics capability of Ver 10, and have a nicer output. This will allow further processing such as attachment of a fructose to a sucrose and other related manipulations.

Comment: @thils, Yes it should be possible. I answered exactly your question since I thought you just wanted to use the .xyz file in a quantum simulation program. Do you want to plot it with the bonds included?

Answer (score 3):

```
pos = ChemicalData["DFructose", "AtomPositions"]/100;
elems = ChemicalData["DFructose", "VertexTypes"];
positions = Transpose[{elems, pos}];
Grid[positions, Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Graphics3D[{ColorData["Atoms", #[[1]]], Sphere[#[[2]], .2]} & /@ 
  positions, Axes -> True, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The ans. is appropriate but what is "nums"...I can't generate the same output because this info. is missing.

Comment: @thils Sorry, it was an old name for `lens`. Typo corrected. Thanks!

Comment: Graphics3D does not work in Ver 10

Comment: @thils Why? http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html

Comment: It looks like you've got the positions of the atoms mixed up. This looks nothing like D-Fructose.

Comment: @RunnyKine Well, that show my broad chemistry ignorance. In fact I wasn't aware that the ordering of "ElementTally" and "VertexTypes" were different. And it resulted in a much simpler code- Thanks for the tip!

Comment: No worries. I wasn't sure initially, I had to visualize it to be certain it was the right order.